# In a JQuery dblclick() listener of <tr>, how to get contents of all child <td> elements, as well as the contents of all <td>'s in table header row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/0cs7umuq/1/)**

```js
$("table tr.table-row").dblclick(function() {
 alert("Double click event received.");
 alert($(this)[0].outerHTML);
  console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="responsive-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Thing</td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>TV</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am writing a JQuery double-click listener for a table row, i.e. HTML `tr` element.

In the HTML table, the `tr` in the **`thead`** element consists of column-names, i.e. name of fields whose values will be given in each `tr` in the **`tbody`**.

Ideally, in my JQuery `dblclick()` listener, I need the names/keys as well as values for all the fields in the row which is double-clicked.  Ideally, like so:

```
Name    : Bob
Place   : Berlin
Animal  : Mouse
Thing   : TV
```

The reason for needing these kinda name-value pairs is that, from my JQuery double click listener, I need to send this data via **`AJAX`** to a PHP script, which does some further server-side processing on it.

For now, all I have been able to get is the *outer HTML* of the double-clicked element. From the output of `console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);`:

```
<tr class="table-row">
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>TV</td>
  </tr>
```

The question is how do I get the value of each  in the  clicked, preferably along with key/name which are in the 's in the table-header-row.

How would *you* do this? Any tips/suggestions/advice is welcome.

Comment: How is PHP related here?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Like I mentioned in the question, I am sending the required data to a PHP script using AJAX for server-side processing. May be someone can suggest me a way to directly get the required data in the required format directly in that PHP script. That is how!

Comment: The tags should be used to identify technologies directly related to the problem. It is irrelevant for the problem here that the JSON is sent from a PHP script. It could be Python, Java or anything without having an impact on the actual problem stated here, as this is frontend related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Output is a `key => value object`.

I grab all information first, do some **trimming** and **removing empty values**. Those clean `Arrays` are `processed_keys` and `processed_values`.

In the last step I assign those `arrays` as `key => value` pairs to my `data` object.

**EDIT:** This is not the shortest solution of course, you could combine the loops for example. But for demonstration purpose this should be enough =).

**Here is the working fiddle:**

```js
$("table tr.table-row").dblclick(function(e) {
  var values = $(e.target).parent().text().split('\n');
  var keys = $('thead').text().split('\n');
  var processed_keys = new Array();
  var processed_values = new Array();
  var data = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    if(keys[i].trim() !== ""){
      processed_keys.push(keys[i].trim());
    }
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i].trim() !== ""){
      processed_values.push(values[i].trim());
    }
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < processed_keys.length; i++){
    data[processed_keys[i]] = processed_values[i];
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="responsive-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Thing</td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>TV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Luke</td>
    <td>Munich</td>
    <td>Giraffe</td>
    <td>Radio</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATED

`target` is what you need instead of `this`.

```js
$("table tr.table-row").dblclick(function(e) {
   var pos = $(e.target).index()
   var name = $(e.target).closest("table").find("tr >td").eq(pos).text()
   console.log(name+": "+$(e.target).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="responsive-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Thing</td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>TV</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note: materialize.min.css gives an error but we dont need it to make this jquery example.

Comment: Would you do that in the JSFiddle I linked? Because it gives me nothing but an error.